# Как правильно воспользоваться обобщённым классом C#?

Tags: c#, .net, menu

Здравствуйте. Я новичок и у меня возник такой вопрос. У меня есть свой обобщенный класс реализующий односвязный список. Хочу создать меню, в котором, можно выбрать какой тип данных я могу туда занести. Пытаюсь сделать что то вроде этого:  `

```
        MyLinkedList list;//знаб что так нельзя
        int c = 0;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1: list = new MyLinkedList<int>();
                    break;
            case 2:
                list = new MyLinkedList<string>();
                break;               

                // и т.д.
        }

      // и дальше использовать созданный список



        `
```

Как это правильно сделать? что использовать вместо MyLinkedList list;??

Comment: "обобщенный класс " - что есть это?

Comment: @Igor это он о Generic'ах

Comment: @LunarWhisper А-а, спасибо.

Comment: Надо использовать информацию о типах.

Answer (score 0):

Если твой список предоставляет не привязанные к конкретному типу методы, которые ты хочешь использовать, то ты можешь:

1. Унаследовать `MyLinkedList<T>` от не Generic-типа `MyLinkedList`.
2. Объявить и реализовать интерфейс `IMyLinkedList`

Ты можешь создать универсальный класс-обёртку над всеми возможными данными и хранить в списке его:

```
class MyNode
{
  public object Value;
}
...
MyLinkedList<MyNode>;
```

Если тебе нужно просто куда-нибудь его положить и как-нибудь передать, то тебе подойдёт упаковка в Object:
`object list;`

Если ты хочешь вызывать какие-нибудь типо-зависимые члены этого типа, но при этом не зная что за тип упакован, то одним из решений будет использовать dynamic, но это ударит по производительности и затруднит понимание кода, приведёт к неожиданным проблемам в неожиданных местах, отключит compile-type валидацию и подсказки IntelliSense:
`dynamic list;`

Так же ты можешь использовать Reflection, Expression или сгенерированный на лету IL-код с unsafe кастом в обход любых проверок...

Всё зависит от того - как и для чего ты хочешь это использовать. Но обычно, всё-таки, при работе с Generic-типами, ты точно знаешь - элементы какого типа у тебя в нём хранятся. Возможно, тебе нужен просто `MyLinkedList<object>` или ты просто пытаешься решить не ту проблему не теми средствами.

Comment: Я представляю параметр, который подставляется в дженерик тип